# SQL Subquery to handle duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am joining to tables, however the table I want to left join has duplicate values for the matching field. I am trying to create a subquery so that when there are duplicates the column value is assigned 'Duplicate' and when there isn't then it takes the value of the join.

Here is simplified query of what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT
    l.Id,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN count(d.db_id) > 1 THEN 'Duplicate'
                ELSE COALESCE(a.name, 'Unknown')
        END
        FROM
            Dynamics AS d
                LEFT JOIN account as a
                ON a.account_id = d.account_id
         WHERE d.db_id = l.Id
         GROUP BY  ld.db_id
    ) as account_name
FROM listings as l
```

However, obviously this doesn't work because a.name is not in the group by clause. I don't want to include it in the group by clause because often the duplicate records have different values for it.

Edit: also important to note that the duplicate rows have the same created date, but often have different account_id's, which is why when I find a duplicate I just want to label it 'Duplicate' and not have to choose one

Sample Expected Result:

Listing Table:
| Id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Dynamics Table:
Id | db_id | account_id
--- | --- | ---
1 |  1 |     1
2 |  1 |     Null
3 |  2 |     2

Account Table:
account_id  | name
--- | ---
1        |    account1
2        |    account2

Expected resulting Table:
Id |       account_name
--- | ---
1 |        Duplicate
2 |        account2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you stated, this can be done with a subquery and joining on the subquery
I'm using `ROW_NUMBER()`, `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` in the subquery to get the rows in order by the `account_id`  and for every row that has the same `account_id`, add 1 to the count of that row's column `RowNum`, then in the outer query, you can use the case to check if the subquery column `RowNum` is equal to 1, if so, use the value from table `account` else show 'Duplicate', to read more about the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function and the key words used in the subquery you can read this (https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/). You can also use the `ORDER BY` in the subquery to order your dynamics by a date or any other column in the `Dynamics` table in case you want the 1st record of each partition to be the most recent or whatever your logic is there:

Edit: Since you stated you don't want to Group By on the name for whatever reason, you can add a `WHERE` clause to this to only take the record if it's `RowNum` is less than 3, this way you get at most 2 records for each account_id, one being the name and the other being duplicate, then you again need to use `ROW_NUMBER()`, `OVER`, and `PARTITION BY` to order the records from greatest to least and take only the top record of each partition ensuring you get the record with name duplicate in cases where there are more than one record with the given id, then join on the listings table. I really don't understand your refusal to just Group By on the name as well, but this does what you asked for. I'd definitely be doing a performance check on this versus Group By including the name and see which is faster.

```
SELECT l.[Id], dx.[Name]
FROM listings AS l
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT d.db_id, d.[Name], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY d.db_id ORDER BY d.[RowNum] DESC) AS [RowNum]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT d.db_id, CASE WHEN d.[RowNum] > 1 THEN 'Duplicate' ELSE COALESCE(a.name, 'Unknown') END AS [Name], d.[RowNum]
        FROM
        (
            SELECT d.account_id, d.db_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.db_id ORDER BY d.db_id) AS [RowNum]
            FROM Dynamics AS d
        ) AS d
        LEFT JOIN account as a
        ON a.account_id = d.account_id
        WHERE d.[RowNum] < 3
    ) AS d
) AS dx
ON dx.db_id = l.Id
WHERE dx.[RowNum] = 1
```

**EDIT:** **Here's a simpler version that I believe returns the results as you want:**

```
SELECT a.[Id], a.[account_name]
FROM
(
    SELECT l.[Id], CASE WHEN dx.db_count > 1 THEN 'Duplicate' ELSE COALESCE(a.Name, 'Unknown') END AS [account_name]
    FROM @dynamic AS d
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT d.db_id, COUNT(d.db_id) AS [db_count]
        FROM @dynamic AS d
        GROUP BY d.db_id
    ) AS dx
    ON dx.[db_id] = d.[db_id]
    LEFT JOIN @accounts AS a
    ON a.account_id = d.[account_id]
    INNER JOIN @listings AS l
    ON l.[Id] = d.[db_id]
) AS a
GROUP BY a.[Id], a.[account_name]
```

Comment: Perhaps this is a spark issue, but when I run this query I don't get any error, but when try an display the results I get a "java.lang.RuntimeException: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: @PalaniThangaraj Your post was tagged as `sql` and `sql server`, I don't know what that has to do with `java.lang.RuntimeException`. Did you try running the query I gave you in `sql management studio`? If it runs and gives you the correct results in your sql engine, then you must have something going wrong outside of this post.

Comment: Yeah, the query you provided doesn't work for me because it is missing some sort of where clause to match it with the outer query table "Listings"

Comment: I also don't think you query works because it doesn't group the duplicates, if any entry has a duplicate I want them to be grouped and return only one row with the value 'Duplicate'

Comment: @PalaniThangaraj Then join the `listings` table on what I gave you and do your `group by`, this was meant to give you an answer to what you want with the duplicate and more than one record with the same id problem. Putting sample data and expected results in your post would also be helpful.

Comment: @PalaniThangaraj I updated my answer to give you your extra requirements.

Comment: I've updated my question to show expected results, thank you for all your help!

Comment: I am totally open to using Group By if it works, but wouldn't the group by not group them if the names for the corresponding duplicate ids are different? (since a lot of the time the duplicates have different names as the user randomly chooses one of the entries and only updates the name value for that entry)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the code below. But, honestly, you will face a lot o stepping stones ahead...

```
SELECT
    l.Id,
    --
    case
        when
            count(*) > 1 then 'Duplicate'
        else
            coalesce(max(acc.name), 'Unknown')
    end as account_name
FROM
    listings as l
        inner join(
            Dynamics d
                left outer join account acc
                on acc.account_id = d.account_id
        )
        on d.db_id = l.id
group by l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lateral join here to keep the query context simple in case you need to retrieve more information later.

```
SELECT l.Id, IIF(d.cnt > 1, 'Duplicate', COALESCE(a.name, 'Unknown')) AS account_name
FROM listings AS l
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT MIN(account_id) AS account_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM Dynamics
  WHERE db_id = l.id
) AS d
LEFT JOIN account AS a ON a.account_id = d.account_id;
```

You need an apply instead of a join since the table `l` is referenced in the subquery.

If you know that there is always at least one matching row in the `Dynamics` table, you should replace `OUTER APPLY` by `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an `OVER` clause to count the rows sharing the same `db_id`, this would keep your joins very clean but you will need `DISTINCT` as the rows would otherwise appear multiple times:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  l.Id,
  IIF(COUNT(d.db_id) OVER (PARTITION BY l.Id) > 1,
    'Duplicate',
    COALESCE(a.name, 'Unknown')
  ) AS account_name
FROM listings AS l
LEFT JOIN Dynamics AS d ON d.db_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN account AS a ON a.account_id = d.account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with. There are other answers in here which will give you the same answer, but I like my approach because the code is readable and makes your intentions clear in what you want...which is a list of listings records and the associated account name.

Depending on the amount of data you are working with, this may or may not be very efficient. `APPLY`'s can be a bit tricky at times.

Based on your post, I interpreted your question as "I want a list of `listings` id's, and their associated account name, but if there's multiple `dynamics`, just show 'Duplicate'".

```sql
SELECT l.id, x.AccountName
FROM dbo.listings l
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT AccountName = IIF(COUNT(*) = 1, MAX(a.[name]), 'Duplicate')
        FROM dbo.dynamics d
            LEFT JOIN dbo.account a ON a.account_id = d.account_id
        WHERE l.id = d.[db_id]
        GROUP BY d.[db_id]
    ) x
```

Explanation:

- Start off with the primary thing you want your query to return...a list of `listings` records...so that's `SELECT id FROM dbo.listings`
- Now we need to add the AccountName column

  - This is where it gets tricky because you either want the account name, or if there's multiple, then you want the word "Duplicate". This is a good place to use an `APPLY`. `APPLY`'s are good when you need to grab a piece of information from another table/set of tables in a 1:many relationship. In this case, you have 1 `listings` record to many `dynamics` records.
  - If you use other programming languages, you can kind of think of an `APPLY` like a ForEach operator. For each row in `listings` we want to get all dynamics records (left joined to `account` in order to get the account name) and `GROUP BY` the `db_id` (FK to listings).
  - Now that we've grouped by the `db_id`, we only have 1 row, so we've eliminated the 1:many relationship. Now we can simply check if the `COUNT(*)` of `dynamics` records is `> 1`...if it is, then return "Duplicate", if there's only 1 row, then return the `account.name`.

One thing to note...In this case...

If the `listings` record has zero `dynamics` records associated with it, then...

- `CROSS APPLY` - will act like an inner join, and will not output the listings record
- `OUTER APPLY` - will act like a left join, and will output the listings record with a NULL account name.

Depending on what you need, you can decide which to use.

---

Edge cases:

- What happens if 1 `listings` record has 2 `dynamics` records, but all of the `account_id`'s are the same? In that case, should we return the name?